# Windows Defender keeps closing up

Tags: windows-server-2003, anti-virus

I have a Windows 2003 server with Windows Defender installed and every time a start WD, after a few hours it just stops running, there's no entries in the event log about it or anything, I've scanned the server and is all clean, just can't figure out why it's stopping with no apparent cause.

Any ideas?

Jaime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it happens during an automated full scan? Maybe it gets stuck on a file that is locked on your server. Did you try to run a manual full scan?

It could also run out of resources if the amount of files scanned. I once run into errors on a folder with many documents. Removing that folder solved the Defender problems, which reappeared as soon as I copied that folder back to the machine.

Anonther workaround you could try: uninstall Windows Defender and reinstall the latest version. Perhaps something  went wrong in the configuration.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, although I've done manual full scans and they complete successfully... I have it setup to do quick scans daily but I'll try reinstalling and post back the results. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One thing I have found is to reboot after this error. Run an install fresh from Microsoft. It seems to work every time.